# How to change the Taskbar location using the Registry?

Tags: windows-10, registry

I have 30 Windows 10 production PC's and try to keep them all reasonably the same but on one PC at least one operator keeps moving the taskbar from the standard bottom position to the right.

There is a setting I can manually change to fix it, but I am running custom software on that PC and would PREFER to do something like change a Registry setting when that software runs.

Any idea which Registry setting I could modify to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Win 10 apps or .NET

Comment: I am programming using the .NET platform on a Windows 10 PC. I think that's relevant.